# Collocations of string/wire/cable + intrasitive verb meaning "cut"

Tags: collocations

I was playing a game with my little children to find out that I got stumped to describe what could happen to a string below

> If you pull a wire/cable/string so hard it could (*intransitive verb
>   meaning cut*)

I managed to go around that but I still want to know the verb/s that could go above.

I though of verbs like rip/cut/break! and used a thesaurus for ideas but nothing beats asking our people for help, our fellow members.

Comment: I think you may want to see this: https://www.stringjoy.com/why-guitar-strings-break/

Comment: Do you mean that the string itself will break, or that the wire could cut *something else*?

Comment: @stangdon well, the OP did say 'intransitive verb meaning'

Comment: For *string* I would say *break* or *snap*. But these might not work as well for  wire and cable or cable.

Comment: @AlanCarmack - Ah, good point.

Comment: Well, I did not expect there will be any difference. Thank you all.